# How to read email using PHP's imap function and cronjob

Tags: php, cron, imap

I have a PHP script which used for reading the emails and then insert details into database. When I run this script from browser it works perfect but when I tried to run this script using Linux cronjob at specified time then it failed.

Note: I already know how to use cron. My other scripts runs perfectly except this one.

Comment: Maybe script uses some http request variables?What error do you have?

Comment: Can you give code of your php file?

Comment: I get this error Unknown: rsh to IMAP server timed out (errflg=1)

Comment: You dont need to use cron for email, just set up a forwarder and point it to your php script. A cron job running every x minutes is just wasted resource for email.

Comment: Could you please tell me the process how can I do this forwarding to read the email from my PHP script.

Comment: The method depends upon your systems. Figure out what you have available then you can ask that question on the appropriate site. Possibly Super user which is another stack exchange site.

Comment: Use Curl then you can solve it

Comment: (Without any code to look at, we're just shooting in the dark. Next time you receive a request for code, as per @Dmitriy's above, please do edit your question. You don't want to acquire too many closed questions, as it can eventually result in an automatic question ban).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using the curl.

I create a cronjob which call my script with its actual URL like below and it works perfectly for me:

```
17 16 * * * /usr/bin/curl https://your_script_url
```

Comment: Curl is often unnecessary. Instead just do `php /path/to/script.php`, to avoid going through the web server. Nevertheless, this does work - WordPress does it your way.